# Make Entity API aware of new custom field

Tags: entities, search

I am using a module that creates a field type "ean_hotel_hotelid".  I am using Search API and need to index this field, but it is not available to be indexed.  Search API will index all fields and field types that are recognized by Entity API.

So I am using an implementation of hook_entity_property_info_alter.  The field data is stored in the database in a field called "field_expedia_hotel_id_ean_hotel_id", but the field_config table has the field set up as field_name "field_expedia_hotel_id" and type "ean_hotel_hotelid".

However, I can not get Entity API to see this new field.  I based my hook implementation on [this](http://ygerasimov.com/add-custom-field-search-api-apachesolr-index).  Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Getter callback for EAN Hotel ID Property.
 */
function bartheme_ean_hotel_id_getter_callback() {
  return variable_get('field_expedia_hotel_id_ean_hotel_id', array());
}

/**
 * Adds 'Hotel ID' (EAN module) field type as an indexable field in Search API.
 */
function bartheme_entity_property_info_alter(&$info) {
  $info['node']['properties']['field_expedia_hotel_id'] = array(
    'type' => 'struct',
    'bundle' => 'hotel',
    'label' => t('Expedia Hotel ID'),
    'sanitized' => FALSE,
    'getter callback' => 'bartheme_ean_hotel_id_getter_callback',
    'property info' => array(
    'type' => 'ean_hotel_hotelid',
    ),
  );
  }
```

I have tried several different variations, but can not get Entity API to recognize this field.  What is wrong?

Comment: I'm making some progress.  I can get this new field type to be recognized by Entity API if I change the 'type' key value to 'text' or 'integer'.  However, the Formatter field is not exposed in Views.  So I assume I need to make the 'type' key value = 'struct'.  I then need to use the 'property info' key to define the additional metadata for this field.  However, I must not be using 'property info' key correctly.  When used as in code above, Entity API does not recognize field.  Syntactically, how would I implement 'property info' key?